# Column does not exist in spring boot Postgres app

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

Hi in my spring boot postgresql application, when i retrieve all record using DAO it show column does not exists.

**ERROR**

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column merchantit0_.id does not exist
  Position: 8
ERROR: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/customerplus].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/customerplus] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column merchantit0_.id does not exist
  Position: 8
```

**Entity Domain**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "merchant_item_category")
public class MerchantItemCategory{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 11)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", nullable = false)
    private Merchant merchant;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**DAO**

```
public List<MerchantItemCategory> getAllMerchantItemCategoryByMerchantId(long id) {
        Session session=getSession();
        List<MerchantItemCategory>itemCategories=session.createQuery("from MerchantItemCategory where merchant.id=:merchantId and isDelete='0' order by categoryName asc")
                .setParameter("merchantId", id)
                .list();
        return itemCategories;
    }
```

I just checked every object and it is correct, But how this error occurring..!

Comment: As the error states: the table "merchant_item_category" has no column "id". Create it or set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property to "update".

Answer (score 4):

A potential cause of this error is when you haven't defined the hibernate "default schema" property.

I fixed this issue by adding line below to my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${your-default-schema-name}
```